# Table row hovering - exclude specific cell?

Tags: css, html-table, css-tables

I made a pricing table that will change the background of the row when hovered.  Due to the way I am using it I ran into two problems.

1. there is a 3 row span I am using to hold the purchase button as I want it vertically aligned in the center with the columns to its left.  I had to use !important to keep the background white on rollover. Fixed.
2. when you rollover the purchase button cell its highlights the first row.  This is what I do not want.  I've tried all sorts of things and rearranged things as well and can't come up with any solution without removing the 3 row span.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ae8uU/)

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">title text</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td class="pricing">price</td>
    <td class="purchase" rowspan="3">purchase button</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td class="pricing">price</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>amount</td>
    <td class="pricing">price</td>
</tr>
</table>


table{
margin:.5em 0 1em 0;
width:100%;
font-size:15px;
}
table th{
padding:0px 0 10px 5px;
}

table td{
padding:2px 5px;
}

table td.purchase{
text-align:right;
width:150px;
vertical-align:middle;
background:#ffffff !important;
}
table td.pricing{
width:130px;
border-left:5px #ffffff solid;
}
table td.details {
padding:0 35px 0 15px;
}

table tr:hover td
{
background-color: #ebf1f6;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can check [**Answer**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/MLULk/1/)

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" scope="row">title text </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="75%" scope="row">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class="amount_table">
          <tr>
            <td>amount</td>
            <td>price</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>amount</td>
            <td>price</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>amount</td>
            <td>price</td>
          </tr>
        </table>    
    </td>
    <td width="25%">Purchace</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
.amount_table tr:hover{
  background:gray
}
```

Comment: Well, actually that's not the answer, since the question was to find a solution without removing the 3 row span.

Comment: I did nothing, but if I would, seems like I'd had to use a little of js.

Comment: Solved but not exact as he want

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement: apply a background color on a table row, as I hovered over the row with the mouse pointer, except on a 'selected' row, that was already highlighted in a different background color.

Using 'pointer-events: none;' achieved exactly what i wanted:  [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwsmith/bwuzrp81/)

```
table#CustOrders tbody tr:hover td {
  background-color: LemonChiffon;
}
table#CustOrders tbody tr#selected {
  background-color: Yellow;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is using  "**pointer-events**" css property. But I am not sure if it is useful here. Check [this](https://coderwall.com/p/qa0hga) link (there is a jsFiddle example available)

Also think about using some javascript code to set the logic you need. I understand that you want to use css only, but js fix can be quite small and obvious here - so why not ?